# Trouble using background-position with hover

Tags: css, background-position

I'm trying to recreate the 'bounce' that tumblr adds to their new post icons on the [dashboard](http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard).

I've been looking around for how to use `background-position` to create that bounce but haven't had any luck so far.

The other questions here have had a problem using `background` and then trying to specify the `background-position` but I'm not using `background` at all.

I wasn't trying to spend a ton of time on this but now I am curious about it.

[Gist for the code](https://gist.github.com/dontoisme/5095950)

[Codepen](http://cdpn.io/wLAoI)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="block blue">
  <div class="inblock light-green"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="block green">
  <div class="inblock orange"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="block yellow">
  <div class="inblock light-blue"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="block blue">
  <div class="inblock light-green"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="block green">
  <div class="inblock orange"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="block yellow">
  <div class="inblock light-blue"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  width:80%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-left:5em;
  background-color: #95A5A6;
}

.block {
  margin: 2em;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  float:left;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.block:hover > .inblock{
  background-color:#E74C3C;
  background-position: top;

}

.inblock {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin: 1.5em;
}

.light-blue {
  background-color:#2980B9

}

.blue {
  background-color:#2C3E50;
}

.green {
  background-color:#27AE60;
}

.yellow {
  background-color:#F1C40F;
}

.orange {
  background-color:#E67E22;
}

.light-green {
  background-color:#2ECC71;
}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't specifically answer your question, but if you're looking to re-create the effect I've created somewhat of a similar effect using the CSS3 `transform` (specifically the `translateY` function) property, with a `transition` to create the 'bounce'. JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/7rsbr/](http://jsfiddle.net/7rsbr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position):

> The background-position CSS property sets the initial position, relative to the background position layer defined by background-origin for each defined background image.

If you look at the HTML (using a developer tool, such as Google Chrome's developer tools), you'll see that Tumblr actually use [a sprite](http://assets.tumblr.com/images/post_icons_sprite_2x.png?3) and then use the `background-position` property to shift the icons up/down using CSS3 transitions.

The `background-position` property isn't doing anything in the code you provided since there has been no `background-image` property set.

If you don't want to use a sprite/image, you can simply use CSS3's `transform` property instead to create the 'bounce' effect. I have created a JSFiddle demonstrating the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/7rsbr/

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. Thanks a bunch!